# Animate-up number with thousand separators

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, react-spring

**When using [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/) to animate-up a number from 0 to x, is it possible to display that number with commas as "thousand separators" (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript))?**

The goal is to display this number as "123,456" - while still animating it up nicely!

```js
const x = 123456;
```

Basic react-spring number animation:

```js
<Spring
    from={{
        number: 0,
    }}
    to={{
        number: x,
    }}
    config={{
        duration: 500
    }}
>
    {props => (
        <div>
            {props.number?.toFixed()}
        </div>
    )}
</Spring>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`{new Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.round(props.number)}`

The NumberFormat() from the Intl API will provide the commas for you where they belong.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Comment: Oh, right, looks like I was overthinking this. You're correct, I can simply format the output react-spring generates (without having to worry about how it does it). However, your answer should be `{new Intl.NumberFormat().format(props.number?.toFixed())}` to ensure there aren't any decimal points in the result (as per the question's code example).

Comment: Do you know what browser support is like for NumberFormat() from the Intl API?

Comment: [Browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a number to a string with some formatting using [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString). Format the value before outputting it with the specified locale.

The example below uses the `EN-us` locale which will use comma's to separate thousands and a dot to indicate decimals.

Or you can omit the value and it will detect the locale of the user.

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');
let count = 10000;

setInterval(() => {
  output.value = count.toLocaleString('EN-us');
  count += 10000;
}, 50);
```

```html
<output id="output"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-spring's `useSpring` hook and `animated` component to create a React component that animates a number.

If you then wrap the `.toFixed(0)` value as a `Number` and call `.toLocaleString("en-US")` it will add the appropriate commas.

Example of a component that counts up from n and utilizes commas.

```js
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

interface AnimatedNumberProps {
  n: number;
}

/**
 * Component that animates from 0 to n
 */
export default function AnimatedNumber(props: AnimatedNumberProps) {
  const { n } = props;

  const { number } = useSpring({ number: n, from: { number: 0 } });

  return (
    <animated.div>
      {number.to((n) => Number(n.toFixed(0)).toLocaleString("en-US"))}
    </animated.div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not `react-spring` but I managed to animate financial values with `framer-motion` if anyone is interested.

So I already had the component for animating regular numbers:

```
import {
  motion,
  useMotionValue,
  useTransform,
  animate,
  type ValueAnimationTransition,
} from 'framer-motion'
import { FC, useEffect } from 'react'

interface AnimateCounterProps {
  start?: number
  target: number
  options?: ValueAnimationTransition<number>
}

export const AnimateCounter: FC<AnimateCounterProps> = ({
  start = 0,
  target,
  options,
}) => {
  const count = useMotionValue(start)
  const rounded = useTransform(count, Math.round)

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = animate(
      count,
      target,
      options ?? { duration: 0.3, ease: 'easeInOut' },
    )
    return animation.stop
  }, [])

  return <motion.span>{rounded}</motion.span>
}
```

and after fidgeting with all responses here I came up with this solution which, I think, is the cleanest yet. It makes use of already existing `AnimateCounter`.

First, I format value with `Intl.NumberFormat` using `formatToParts`
which gives me a nice structure:

```
[
    {
        "type": "integer",
        "value": "2137"
    },
    {
        "type": "decimal",
        "value": ","
    },
    {
        "type": "fraction",
        "value": "49"
    },
    {
        "type": "literal",
        "value": " "
    },
    {
        "type": "currency",
        "value": "zł"
    }
]
```

Then we only need to look for numeric values that are stored in type `integer` and `fraction` and pass those values as number to our `AnimateCounter` and the rest of the elements from this array we can render as usual.

```
import { AnimateCounter } from './animate-counter'

interface AnimateFinancialProps {
  target: number
  intlFormatter: Intl.NumberFormat
}

const NUMBER_PARTS = ['integer', 'fraction']

export const AnimateFinancial = ({
  target,
  intlFormatter,
}: AnimateFinancialProps) => {
  const parts = intlFormatter.formatToParts(target)

  return (
    <div>
      {parts.map(({ value, type }) => {
        if (NUMBER_PARTS.includes(type)) {
          return (
            <AnimateCounter
              target={Number(value)}
              key={[type, value].join('-')}
            />
          )
        }
        return value
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
const Example = () => {
  const polishFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pl', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'PLN',
  })

  return <AnimateFinancial target={2137.49} intlFormatter={polishFormatter} />
}
```

If you are hell-bend on using `react-spring` I think the similar approach can be utilized.